Maximal spectra of $A_S$ and $A/I$, where $S = 1 + I$
Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $I$ be a ideal of it. Let $S = 1 + I$. I want to characterize the maximal ideals of the localization $A_S$. Specifically speaking, I want to prove the following statement.

The maximal spectra $\operatorname{m-Spec} (A_S)$ and $\operatorname{m-Spec} (A/I)$ are homeomorphic.

I find it hard to find a proof. Most things I know are about the prime spectrum. I know that in Atiyah, the saturation of $S$ is determined and it seems to have a relationship with the maximal ideals, that is, $\bar{S}$ is the complement of all maximal ideals of $A$ containing $I$. I also know from Matsumura that $A_S / IA_S \simeq (A/I)_{\bar{S}}$. However, I have no idea about combining them to a proof of this statement.
Any advice is appreciated.

The elements of $S=1+I$ become invertible in $A/I$, this is why we get a homomorphism of $A$-algebras $S^{-1} A \to A/I$. It is surjective with kernel $J := S^{-1} I$. Hence there is a homeomorphism between the maximal ideals of $A/I$ and those maximal ideals of $S^{-1} A$ that contain $J$. It remains to prove that actually every maximal ideal of the localization contains $J$. In other words, $J$ must be included in the Jacobson radical. In general, the Jacobson radical consists of those elements $x$ such that for every other element $y$ the element $1-xy$ is invertible. So in our case we need to verify that for every $x \in I$ and every $y/s \in S^{-1} A$ the element $1 - xy/s$ is invertible in the localization. Up to a unit this is $s - xy$, and this is in $S$ since $s \in S = 1 + I$ and $xy \in I$.
